# Ionic React Page Transition

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I have an Ionic React project using the `blank` template from ionic/cli: `ionic start`.

For reference purposes, I also created a `conference` template sample application. After working for a while I saw that the page transition in the `conference` template is smooth coming from right to left when changing pages.

I would also like to do that in my app, but I didn't find the particular piece of code that does that. Any help in finding it out?

**Update**

My App component:

```js
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <AuthenticationProvider>
          <Route path="/login" component={AuthenticationPage} exact />
          <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Redirect to="/login" />} />

          <SignupProvider>
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignupPage} exact />
          </SignupProvider>
        </AuthenticationProvider>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);

export default App;
```

My SignupPage:

```js
const SignupPage: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {
    return (
        <IonPage id='signup-page'>
            <Stuff/>
        </IonPage>
    );
};

export default SignupPage;
```

Comment: my hunch is that you are not using the ionic-router correctly but really need to see code example

Comment: @AaronSaunders sure, I added the App component and a Page. If it's not enough, let me know. I'm new to react/ionic and routers so for sure I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this... I ha seen weird behavior when I breakup my routes in routerOutlet

```
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <AuthenticationProvider>
          <SignupProvider>
            <Route path="/login" component={AuthenticationPage} exact />
            <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Redirect to="/login" />} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignupPage} exact />
          </SignupProvider>
        </AuthenticationProvider>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. And even if it did being mandatory to put all the routes inside all the providers doesn't sound good to me. Something else must be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you by chance used the `href` attribute instead of the `routerLink` attribute in your links? It should look like this:

```js
<IonRouterLink routerLink="/register">Register</IonRouterLink>
```

Of course you can also use it on other components than `IonRouterLink` like:

```js
<IonItem routerLink="/login">...</IonItem>
```